# Is this melody in a particular scale?

Tags: guitar, scales

I've trying to play Calamaro's Sin Documentos intro. The melody goes like this in Tab notation:

[image]

I've been able to identify the notes and play along, but I was wondering if the melody is in a particular scales. D major doesn't seem to fit, and I was hoping to get some help here.

**Update:**

Per general request, I'm including Standard Notation also:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a lot of patience for tab.  I play by ear or from standard notation.  What are the notes of the scale?

Comment: Could you get the standard notation? Would make things easier.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude, I did as requested

Comment: Please forgive me for being picky, but if it's in Gm, it'll have a Bb and an Eb, instead of the A# and D# that's arrived.The F# is fine, though, as that's the leading note used in G harmonic minor. For those who read dots, it will make life much more comfortable !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be in G minor, with the slightly odd sounding 4th fret 4th string note being the leading note (F#), part of a D chord, the V of Gm. The reason you thought D was that the first note is indeed a D. There are many pieces of music that do not use the key note to start. Most will use it to finish.As this actually does !

So the key's G minor, but that only narrows it down to 3 sets of notes that we call scales. Like a lot of Spanish flavoured tunes, this one seems to use the G harmonic minor scale notes.This doesn't mean though, that just because a song's in a particular key/scale, it won't use other notes as well - see another question posed today.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Two additional questions:Is there a particular method/technique to identify the Scale of a melody? What are those "bars" that are linking quarter notes in standard notation?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any 'bars' linking quarter notes. Do you mean the bars joining eighth notes (quavers) together,as in bars 8 and 10 ? If so, they're just instead of single tails for each individual note. Some are not joined - as in bar 14, because the bar in 4/4 is usually written so that it can be split into 2 halves of 2 beats each, which makes bar 11 not as well written as it might have been.But that's the way things can turn out nowadays !